# Does the category of smooth manifolds over $\mathbb{R}$ have an initial object?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds

Does the category of smooth manifolds over $\mathbb{R}$ have an initial object?

And if not, is there a natural way to transform this category so that it has an initial object.

I think that the zero-dimensional manifold which should be the same as the trivial vector space is a final object. But I don't see how to map this final object to a smooth manifold. So I would think that there is no initial object.

Comment: The empty set .

Comment: I don't understand the "So" at the beginning of the last sentence of the question. There are plenty of categories (besides the category of smooth manifolds) that have final and initial objects but no map from the final object to the initial object --- for example the category of sets and the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Dear Andreas, I understand the confusion. It was caused by a misunderstanding in my part. I thought that when a category has both an initial and final object, these have to be the same object. However, this is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $e$ is the initial object of a category $C$, for every object $X$ of $C$ there exists a unique morphism $i_X:e\rightarrow X$.

Suppose that $e$ is the initial object of $Mani$ the category of manifolds, if $X$ has more than two points, and $e$ is not empty, there are more than two distinct maps $e\rightarrow X$.Therefore there exists an initial object if it is assumed that the empty set is a manifold.